# JS removeChild only works half the time

Tags: javascript

```
var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('release'),graph.removeChild.bind(graph));
```

In Firefox and Safari (haven't tested others) this removes only the even indexed elements, why?

The HTMLCollection is indexed from 0 to the correct length incrementing by 1, and all elements are present. I get the same behavior with a normal for loop too, so it's probably not some weird forEach incompatibility. In fact if I use the function `function(e,i,a){console.log(e.innerHTML);graph.removeChild(e)}` instead, all the innerHTML gets logged, but still only the even indexed nodes get removed.

Comment: thats a very long and difficult to understand line. i would try to break it into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) which returns live HTMLCollection. So what happens is that index of this collection shifts once the item is removed (collection is updated automatically), which results in undeleted left-over items.

```js
var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('release'), graph.removeChild.bind(graph));
```

```html
<div id="graph">
    <div class="release">release 1</div>
    <div class="release">release 2</div>
    <div class="release">release 3</div>
</div>
```

Use non-live NodeList, for example returned by [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.release'), graph.removeChild.bind(graph));
```

```js
var graph = document.getElementById('graph');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.release'), graph.removeChild.bind(graph));
```

```html
<div id="graph">
    <div class="release">release 1</div>
    <div class="release">release 2</div>
    <div class="release">release 3</div>
</div>
```